# Refreshing ng-repeat without $scope, without new request to sever

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controlleras

I have a table with this content:

```
 <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="result in ctrl.result track by $index">
       <td ng-bind="$index+1"></td>
       <td ng-bind="::result.title"></td>
       <td> <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click='ctrl.deleteItem(result)'>Delete</button></td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
 vm.deleteItem = function (result) {
        myService.deleteItem(result.id)
           .then(function (response) {
                vm.result.splice(result, 1);
            });
    };
```

As you see, the `vm.result` has changed if the item be deleted successfully. 
Now, the item deleted in db, so we have response and then the item has been removed from `vm.result`, too. But the list hasn't updated in browser.
As you see, I use `controller as` approach and not  `$scope` .

Comment: Hi you have to use  vm.result in your html because in your controller u have vm.result if its only $scope.result only it will be considered as result in html so change vm.result in html

Comment: you should try removing `::` from `ng-bind`. as it's not only readonly data!

Comment: @gayathri, I have set the myController as ctrl. so I use vm. in controller, and ctrl. in html.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak, ++vote to your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the item this way:

```
vm.result.splice(vm.result.indexOf(result), 1);
```

The first [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) parameter should be the index of element rather than element itself.

Comment: I accepted the answer. But @Dhaval Marthak's comment helps me, too. If I didn't remove the ::, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Elnaz Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     var index = vm.result.findIndex(function(item) {
                if (item.id == test.id) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            if (index !== -1) {
                // Removing the test from list;
                vm.result.splice(index, 1);
}
```

check based on id from the array test.id is the id of the element u r deleting